# QGIS hyperlink to images using EVIS and relative path

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins

Just wondering if anyone has experience creating relative paths in the EVIS plugin for JPEGs.
Basically got a set of points that id like to have linking to some JPEGs. They are all stored
in the same database but not in the same folder.

It's been a few years since I've had to use relative paths and cant quite seem to track down the reason why its not working. Is there a general rule for the end portion in the image path column? e.g., just the folder the images are in or it and a set number of layers above?

[image]